# Making Python Use Code in My Directory (not that in /usr/...)

Tags: python, path

I am trying to work on a Python library that is already installed on my (Ubuntu) system. I checked out that library, edited some files, and wrote a small script to test my changes. Even though I put my script in the same folder as that of the library, it seems Python is using the installed version instead (the one in `/usr/share/pyshared/...`).

This is my directory structure:

```
src
+ my_package
    - my_script.py
+ library_package
    - lots_of_code
```

How can I tell Python to use the code in my directory, not the installed one?

Comment: For each of the (correct) answers which tell you to modify `PYTHONPATH`, don't forget the precedence rules. Items on the left in that variable over-ride items to the right in it, and items in the local directory for your code beat that variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dictate where `python` searches for modules using the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable:

> When a module named spam is imported,
>   the interpreter searches for a file
>   named spam.py in the current
>   directory, and then in the list of
>   directories specified by the
>   environment variable PYTHONPATH. This
>   has the same syntax as the shell
>   variable PATH, that is, a list of
>   directory names. When PYTHONPATH is
>   not set, or when the file is not found
>   there, the search continues in an
>   installation-dependent default path;
>   on Unix, this is usually
>   .:/usr/local/lib/python.

from http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Answer (score 3):

Lets consider a more general issue. In the /usr/share/pyshared/ there are lots of modules. You wish to override just one of the modules. Say the module name is xyz.py. And it happens to use other modules in /usr/shared/pyshared also.

Say we create $HOME/mylibs and add $HOME to Python's sys.path.

Now wherever we have to use xyz, we do something like

```
from mylibs import xyz
```

If we wish to revert back to the original xyz, we try:

```
import xyz # picks up from /usr/shared/pyshared
```

I wonder if this kind of approach would be more general. You mask only those modules which you are overriding and keep others in use as usual.

Answer (score 3):

```
import sys
from os.path import join, dirname, pardir

sys.path.insert(0, join(dirname(__file__), pardir))
```

This will check the `src` directory for any python modules, and will look there first.
So even if you have a module with the same name installed elsewhere, this will cause python to load the local one.

[`sys.path documentation`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path).

Answer (score 1):

Check the complete path that Python uses through `sys.path`.  You should be able to add to the path (in front for precedence).

Of course, you can also use PYTHONPATH environment variable or work-around using `.pth` files.

Answer (score 0):

It might work if you set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include that directory, e.g.:

```
$ cd src
$ export PYTHONPATH=./library_package
$ python my_package/my_script.py
```